# Show warning when using specific data

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I need to show a warning or message when the user tries to use specific columns in their SQL queries. I know its kind of vague and specific, but I wonder if it's possible. Is it?

Comment: Show warning where? In Hue? Have you asked the Hue user group?

Comment: Sorry, not a assiduous StackOverflow user. What is the Hue user group? Well, this is a very specific use, but we need to show a warning message to the user when using specific columns in their queries in HUE. I think that is not possible, but I want to make sure it is not by asking to more experienced HUE users.

Comment: You can *limit* Hive results via Sentry or Ranger, but if you want an alert, that requires extra code. The hue developers are here - https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!forum/hue-user